# visual studio command prompt adding web service with authentication

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, authentication, command-prompt

I need to test a web service in visual studio command prompt.

This web service needs authentication in order to be added or created.

How do I set those authentication (ie: The username and password needed to pass the web service)?

Comment: What kind of service? Have you written the console application to call the service? What's your exact next problem?

Comment: i am trying to call a webservice some one has created for me to consume. it needs authentication before i can access the web service. so before putting it to code i need to test it first.

Comment: No, just write a simple console application and use "Add Service Reference" to consume the service. You don't need to "test it first".

Answer (score 0):

Try [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/):

`wget --http-user=<user> --http-password=<pass> https://<url>`

For the webcall arguments see [here](http://www.nilzorblog.com/2012/05/using-wget-to-call-wcf-services.html) e.g.

`wget --post-file "hello.xml" --header "content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8" --header "SOAPAction: http://tepmuri.org/myservice/IService/Hello" http://localhost/Service.svc`

Comment: for clarification. do i just need to type it in wcf test cmd?

Comment: wget is just a command line executable; you'd download it, put it in your path, and then execute it from the command line